# iPhone: Can I take samples from garage band and use them in my app?

Tags: iphone, sample

Not quite a programming question, but here goes.

Lets say, for example, I create a 'drums' iPhone app. (don't worry, I'm not making a drum app, way to many of these already!)

For the drum sounds, would it be OK to directly record drum sounds from garage band and use them as the drum sounds in the app?

Or - is there some legal agreement stopping this? It is perfectly ok to make songs with the garage band instruments, so is it ok to make instruments with the instruments?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IANAL, but [this](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2931) indicates to me that you cannot use the loops in your application:

> ...however, individual audio loops may
>   not be commercially or otherwise
>   distributed on a standalone basis, nor
>   may they be repackaged in whole or in
>   part as audio samples, sound effects
>   or music beds."
>
> So don't worry, you can make
>   commercial music with GarageBand, you
>   just can't distribute the loops as
>   loops.

Comment: I am also not a lawyer (IAANAL), but the way I interpret that passage is that you cannot distribute the loops "as is", but you could use them to make your own songs.